# Library-like approach for helpers and utility functions

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working on a project which uses vanilla JS for primary way of DOM manipulation and I ended up with having plenty of utility/helper functions to wrap DOM methods for consistency and some additional effects.

I ended up with bunch of similar helpers like these:

```
export const containsClass = (el, class) => {
  return el.classList.contains(class)
}

export const selectAll = (class) => {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll(class)]
}
```

I'm considering using a library like approach doing something like this instead:

```
const myHelpers = (class, el) => {
  return new Mono.prototype.init(class, el)
}

myHelpers.prototype = {
  init: (class, el) => {
     this.class = class
     this.el = el
   }
  selectAll: (class) => {
      return [...document.querySelectorAll(class)]
  }
}

export const someShortAlias = myHelpers.prototype
```

*(Note that the code is bundled via Webpack and I'm using import/export statements, that's why I didn't go for an IIFE)*

My thinking was that this would clear up the global name space and keep the code more organized. As it was pointed out in the comments, since I'm using modules this won't have any benefits of clearing up the namespace.

So the reason I want to give this a try is merely experimental at this point. However I haven't used this approach before and I'm not sure if doing it this way will affect the overall evaluation performance or cause other issues. All the methods are working fine, I'm just looking suggestions for improving the second approach.

Comment: If you're using modules and have an individual `export` for each function, how does the global namespace need any cleaning up? The point of modules is that things don't exist outside of the module unless they're `exported` and then `import`ed by another module.

Comment: That's a good point, I was thinking clearing up long import statements but that can be done via importing the utility file with `import * as` too. I guess I just wanted to try a different approach for the sake of it, you're correct that it doesn't appear to have any benefits in terms of namespace.